# Cannto cast from linkedhashmap to dummyobject. Java generics issue

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am using generics in the below way but getting cast exception on getUserObject method where i expect i would pass the class type and the key to retrive the object from the map and then type cast it accordingly. But for some strange reason, i get classcast exception from LinkedHashMap to dummyobject.In my understanding i should never receive a LinkedHashMap object in the output of userObjects.get(objName). Casting comes later. Can somebody put some light on this. I may be missing something very elementary

I see if i change the generic from *T extends Object* to *DummyObject* for testing it is working. So i believe there is something wrong with my generic declaration.

> Here is my InputUserObject class :

```
public class InputUserObject {

private Map<String, Object> userObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public InputUserObject() {
    super();
}

public InputUserObject(Map<String, Object> userObjects) {
    super();
    this.userObjects = userObjects;
}

public Map<String, Object> getUserObjects() {
    return userObjects;
}

public <T extends Object> void setUserObjects(Map<String, T> userObjects) {
    this.userObjects = (Map<String, Object>) userObjects;
}

public <T extends Object> void setUserObject(String key, T userObject) {
    this.userObjects.put(key, userObject);
}

public <T extends Object> T getUserObject(String objName, Class<T> type){
    return type.cast(userObjects.get(objName));

}
}
```

> Here is my DummyObject class which i am using as an exemplary class:

```
    public class DummyObject implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8068197244998284106L;
    public String x="default";
    public String y="0";

    public DummyObject() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DummyObject(String x, String y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DummyObject [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }


}
```

And then i am using the below code for testing the code. Creating a dummyobject, putting it into InputUserObject property userObjects. And then want to retrive it from the userObjects map in generic way as i want to put any other object also into the userObjects map.

```
DummyObject testX = new DummyObject("test","5");
   InputUserObject testObj = new InputUserObject();
   testObj.setUserObject("dummyObjectTest", testX);

   DummyObject x = obj.getUserObject("dummyObjectTest", DummyObject.class);
```

Here i am getting the error on the last line that 
: **java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.controller.vo.DummyObject**. I am missing something elementary but how can i insert multiple different type of objects into the hashmap and can retrieve it using generics.. is my actual concern out of this code

Comment: T with "extends Object" is pointless, just T would do. Then: provide a real [mcve]. That *obj* variable in your code, where is that coming from. And hint: casting can't magically turn an apple into a stone. You can only cast things that ARE what you are casting to. LinkedHashMap isn't your dummy class, so casting is impossible. I think you should do some more research on the basics, instead of inventing things...

Comment: this is a minimal verifiable working code .. but yes i agree not very readable. I have shown all the objects , methods in the single code snap area here. you see dummyobject is a very simple object that i am passing in the inputuserobject and storing in the Map with the key dummyObjectTest. There can by any other type of object that i can add into the map and i just want to retrieve it passing the key and class type in the getUserObject method

Comment: If you want to put any kind of Object into this container you shouldn't use a generic type parameter at all. If you want to be able to put different objects of the same type or interface into the container then your approach comes close to how it should be. However the code as shown does not even compile because of multiple issues. Please put exactly what you wrote, compiled and executed in here.

Comment: Kindly check now. Please do not go into coding conventions, i am here just focusing on retrieving the object

Comment: The edited code i have pasted.. is actually working. my problem was related to something else as i have not unit tested the implementation. The generic implementation is working. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can defer the casting at this point. Just like below and cast it where you consume it.

```
public T getUserObject(String objName) {
  return userObjects.get(objName);
}
```

To generalize, all the objects that are set into map must have a common parent type(T).

Comment: it is same thing Dinesh